# Nothing happens when seeding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails application I have a simple `seeds.rb`:

```
employee_list = [
  ["Kerckhaert", "Martijn", "M", "Pacificatiestraat 22", "Antwerpen", "2000", "0468130781", "033691307", "martijn_kerckhaert@hotmail.com", "martijnmartijn", "martijnmartijn"],
  ["van Lent", "Matthias", "M", "Dorpstraat", "Belsele", "9111", "029301293", "129302193012", "matthias@hotmail.com", "matthiasmatthias", "matthiasmatthias"]]


employee_list.each do |name, firstname, sex, street, city, zip, country, phone, mobile, email, password, password_confirmation|
  Employee.create(name: name, firstname: firstname, sex: sex, city: city, zip: zip, country: country, phone: phone, mobile: mobile, email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password_confirmation, birthdate: Date.today)
end
```

But when I run `rake db:seed` it does nothing.

[image: rake db seed]

Comment: Try with Employee.create! then there may some exception raise. Please check.

Comment: please paste your model to see if it doesn't pass validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your array is missing `country`, which likely makes the validations fail, because `2000` is now passed as the country, `martijn_kerckhaert@hotmail.com` as the mobile, etc.

As someone mentioned in the comments, you can use `create!` to raise an error when they do. This will help you trouble shoot.

You might also be better off using hashes for this, as it is more readable, and robust. E.g.:

```
employees = [
  { name: "Kerckhaert",
    firstname: "Martijn",
    sex: "M",
    street: "Pacificatiestraat 22",
    city: "Antwerpen",
    country: "Belgium",
    zip: "2000",
    phone: "0468130781",
    mobile: "033691307",
    email: "martijn_kerckhaert@hotmail.com",
    password: "martijnmartijn",
    password_confirmation: "martijnmartijn" }
]

employees.each { |employee| Employee.create!(employee) }
```

Comment: Fixed it, I'm officially blind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest here:

create method returns true/false value then there is no way to letting you know that object is saving or not.

instead of using create, you should use create! here so that you will know about the validation errors.